# After recursive search of my json object how to determine data type for looping data

Tags: python, json

I have a recursive function that examines a json object. It captures the data when I try to loop the data, it works for one but not the other.  I need help determining what type of data the returned data is show I can loop the data.

```
targetType = 'equal'
def find_data(lookup_key, jsonData, search_result = []):
    if type(jsonData) == dict:
        for key, value in  jsonData.items():
            if targetType == 'equal' and key == lookup_key:
                search_result.append(value)
            elif targetType == 'regex' and pattern.search(key):
                search_result.append(value)
            find_data(lookup_key, value, search_result)
    elif type(jsonData) == list:
        for element in jsonData:
            find_data(lookup_key, element, search_result)
    return search_result
```

```
json_obj = {
"data": [
    {"stats":[{"num":1,"Count":[0,1,2]},{"num":2,"Count":[3,4,5]}, {"num":3,"Count":[6,7,8]},
            {"num":4,"Count":[9,10,11]}, {"num":5,"Count":[12,13,14]},
            {"num":6,"Count":[15,16,17]},{"num":7,"Count":[18,19,20]}]},
    {"settings":[{"num":8,"Channel1":[[21,22,23],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}]}]}
target_key = "Count"
#target_key = "Channel1"
data = find_data(target_key,json_obj, [])
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

When ran with `target_key = "Count"` a item (list) prints one per loop.  When I use `target_key = "Channel1"` the loop fails I have to to use `for item in data[0]`.  How can I determine which loop to use.  I tried `if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in data):` to determine it is was a nested loop, but both return true.

Here is the return from Count `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20]]`

here is the return from Channel1 `[[[21, 22, 23], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]`

Comment: Return `(type(search_result), search_result)`? (Though the caller could just call `type` on the value you already return itself.) By the way, [don't use `[]` as the default value for `search_result`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1126841)

Comment: @chepner they are both returning `<class 'list'>`, which both are lists.  but that's not helping resolve my issues.  I have removed `[]` as well.

Comment: They are both lists. Python doesn't have more specific runtime types like `list[int]` or `list[list[int]]`. You're going to need some sort of *a priori* information about the schema used, or the consumer will have to, for example, check if a value is iterable before trying to iterate over it.

Comment: Will the data format be consistent? Can you determine how to iterate based on the target_key?

Comment: The problem is not with the code, the problem is with the problem statement & requirements. How are Count and Channel1 different in nature? If the only thing is that Channel1 has a nested list, you could just flatten the results to level-1 nesting

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues you confirmed my suspicion.  I assumed the code was all correct.  It's just a data issue.  @wwii the format should be consistent.  So I can just target `Count` or `Channel1`